# How to group sprites in cocos2d for touch detection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use this code example to detect whether sprite is touched.

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];

  if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint))
{}
```

I have many sprites, and  I must copy that code many times for each of them just changing sprite names. How can I make this process a bit shorter ? Making a `NSArray`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have get your question right, you can use for loop and check all children. Something like this-

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

for (CCSprite *spr in self.children) {
    if ([spr isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]]) {

    float distance = pow(spr.position.x - location.x, 2) + pow(spr.position.y - location.y, 2);
    distance = sqrt(distance);

    if (distance1 <= 150) {
        //do something with your sprite
    }
}
```

}